# How to Show in TimePickerDialog extra 1 Hours

Tags: java, android

How to Add Extra 1 Hour in Time Picker Dialog.
eg.:- If Current Hour is 4.00 Pm then I want to show 5.00 pm in Time Picker.

```
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(CheckOut.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                  int minute) {

                                tvTimeSelect.setText("Delivery Time : "+hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                                timePickerDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
```

Please tell me Solution ...

Comment: Check timePickerDialog.update(17,0); to set for 5:00 PM

Answer (score 3):

You need to maintain consistency.
If you are getting HOUR_OF_DAY then you need to set the same

**Option 1** : using HOUR_OF_DAY

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(CheckOut.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            tvTimeSelect.setText("Delivery Time : "+hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            timePickerDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
```

**Option 2** : using HOUR

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(CheckOut.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            tvTimeSelect.setText("Delivery Time : "+hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            timePickerDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);` instead of `c.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);`

Answer (score 1):

Check this,Tested it's working

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
mcurrentTime.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            tvTimeSelect.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
mTimePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you change it to this if you want 12H instead of 24H?

> mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html